# Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: StaticResource

Tags: salesforcedx

I've just started learning Salesforce DX.

I was following this tutorial https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/sfdx_get_started/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_create_visuals
I didn't have a "view" in Static Resource, so I created one with default parameters. After that I added `leaflet`as it is told in the tutorial.
After that I tried running `sfdx force:source:pull` but I got `ERROR:  Can't retrieve non-customizable CustomObject named: StaticResource.`

Running `sfdx force:source:status` shows

```
=== Source Status
STATE       FULL NAME                 TYPE            PROJECT PATH
──────────  ────────────────────────  ──────────────  ────────────
Remote Add  StaticResource.resources  ListView
Remote Add  leaflet                   StaticResource
```

I tried searchig the web, but I couldn't find anything helpfull.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it appears that ListView is currently not a supported Metadata API Type (for first-generation packages).
See here: [**Supported Metadata API Types**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_supported_mdapi_types.htm)

It is however supported by second-generation packages, which is currently in BETA.
See here: [**Supported Component Types (Beta)**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_plan_component_types.htm#sfdx_dev_dev2gp_plan_component_types)

**In the meantime, you can try one of two things:**

1. Exclude the Static Resource List View from your source: (see instructions here: [**How to Exclude Source When Syncing or Converting**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm)
2. If you don't need the Static Resource List View, simply delete it from your Scratch Org

Comment: Hi, thank  you for the solution. I got confused in Static Resource UI and I created a view, althought I didn't have to and it was what caused a problem. I deleted a view and it pulled ok